# ML-Kit - transmission of personal data and compliance with EU GDPR

Tags: privacy, google-mlkit

My team is considering implementing Googles on-device ML-Kit on our apps to utilize its text recognition and barcode scanning capabilities.

It has come to my attention that Google recommends iOS app distributors to declare that Network request sender IP-addresses are collected for diagnostics and usage analytics (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/ios-data-disclosure).

This declaration is not stated on the page for Google Play Data Disclosure requirements (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/android).

I was hoping to get an answer on these two concerns:

- Will Google collect end-user IP-addresses if the on-device ML-Kit APIs are implemented in our iOS app?
  o  If yes, is there any way for us to mask the IP address or entirely disable the transmission of such data.
- Will Google collect or in any other way process end-user IP-addresses if the on-device ML-Kit APIs are implemented in our Android app?
  o  If yes, is there any way for us to mask the IP address or entirely disable the transmission of such data.

With the case of Google Analytics, several EU governments have ruled utilization of the tool to be against EU laws, since Google can not guarantee that any personal data is not sent outside EU.
I am wondering if the same case would apply to application of the ML-Kit tool

Thank you in advance

I have searched through the web and seen no requests or declarations on this matter, from Google or official forums.